# solution of a Cauchy problem (unique existence)

Tags: real-analysis

Prove unique existence of  the solution $u(t)$ of the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{cases} 
u'(t) = t(\frac{\pi}{3}-\arctan y(t)) \\
u(0) = 2
\end{cases}

$f(t,y)=t(\frac{\pi}{3}-\arctan y(t))\\$

$f \in C^0(R^2)$ so for the Peano  theorem the solution exists locally  $\\$

$\partial y f=-\frac{x}{1+y^2} $ , $\partial y \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ 
so $f$ is locally lipschitz for $y$ uniform in $t.\\$

For Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem I have unique existence locally.

how can I prove global existence in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $f$ is globally Lipschitz in $y$ on any fixed finite time interval $[-T,T]$ with $T>0$. Thus each step of Picard iteration will increase the size of your interval of definition of the solution by a fixed amount (something like $1/L$ where $L$ is your Lipschitz constant) provided that you remain within $[-T,T]$. Thus you can eventually fill out $[-T,T]$ with your solution regardless of what $T$ is. This gives global existence.

Comment: $|\partial y f| \le |x|$ so f has a sublinear growth for y ? so for the global unique existence theorem the solution exists on R?

Comment: @Ian, sorrry for necroposting, but I have a the same question for the same problem: in this case, Giulia B. was trying to show sublinearity, but it was sufficient to note that is it globally Lipschitz, therefore one can apply iteratively the local existence theorem, right?

Comment: @andereBen Yep, you can patch together global existence from iteratively applying local existence. That's what I was trying to say here.

Comment: now everything is clearer to me. Thanks for your patience :)